# WIX 3.8 Silent Installation

Tags: winforms, wix, visual-studio-2013, silent-installer

I have a simple WinForm Application en Visual Studio 2013, Framework 3.5 and I use WIX to get the .MSI file.

I want to do a Silent Installation so i use

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i foo.msi /qn";
p.Start();
```

The problem is that using /qn the installation did no work.

If I do the installation without that parameter, the application is installed.

Comment: See [How To: Get a Log of Your Installation for Debugging](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/get_a_log.html). Check your [InstallExecuteSequence](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/installexecutesequence.html) vs [InstallUISequence](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/installuisequence.html). Check the return value of `p.Start` and the final value of `p.ExitCode`.

Comment: Thanks, I looked the Log file.. It's give me an error 'MainEngineThread is returning 1603' I do not what it means. Any way, I get a Silent Instalation, only thing reminder it to Hide Progress Bar..

Comment: possible duplicate of [WIX 3.8 msiexec.exe /quiet Error 1603](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440440/wix-3-8-msiexec-exe-quiet-error-1603)

Answer (score 0):

You should post the complete verbose log somewhere - 1603 doesn't usually just pop out of the blue. There may be a custom action failing, perhaps because it's expecting properties that were not set because it's silent.  Also, if your install requires elevation then the install will fail because a silent install will not show an elevation dialog, and that will show in the verbose log.