# WIX 3.8 msiexec.exe /quiet Error 1603

Tags: wix, windows-installer, silent-installer

I am using WIX 3.8, Windows 8 Pro, Visual Studio 2013, and I am doing a Silent Installation.

When I run with no /quiet arguments, Ir runs OK. But when I put "/quiet", nothin happend.

There is some problems with /qn Arguments... Any other Arguments Runs OK.

> string arg = " SetupWIX.msi";
>
> ```
>             Process p = new Process();
>
>             p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
>             p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
>             p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i " + arg +" /quiet /l*v log.txt";
>             p.Start();
> ```

And it give error 3.

MainEngineThread is returning 1603.

Any Ideas?

Tahnks

Comment: Can you share the log.txt content?

Comment: It is too long.. I do not which part.  If you want me I can send it by email. Thanks

Comment: send to chrpai@iswix.com

Comment: Look in the log for 'value 3' there may be clues just above that line.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the log you sent me, your MSI need to be elevated.

Not all MSI's do. Most do.  If you are installer in a per-machine context and/or writing to restricted areas ( Program Files, HKLM, Windows an so on ) you'll need elevation.   Typically when you double click an MSI the UI sequence runs as standard user and then when it  transitions to the Execute sequence it'll prompt for elevation if required.  However when you run /quiet it can't do that so it just fails instead.   The two ways around this are to elevate the calling process or first 'advertise' the MSI so that the system trusts it.   In that case the UI->Exec elevation happens automatically without a UAC request.

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVE IT!! Thanks yopu all for your time

I was MIssing

> p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

I did not know I need Administrator Privilegies to execute "/quiet".

Comment: "/quiet" doesn't require Admin.  Your MSI requires Admin.  Quiet just suppresses MSI's ability to ask for elevation.  See my answer below.